# How to display var_dump(unserialize($data)) each item in newline

Tags: php, serialization, memcached, var-dump

```
$data=memcache->get($key)
if(!empty($data))
{ 
  var_dump(unserialize($data));
}
```

How can I get each item in a new line instead of displaying as paragraph array.?

Comment: do you want to store each item to a variable?

Comment: Is it for debugging only? If yes then add `echo '<pre>';` before the dump.

Comment: actually I am sending data to memcache using serialize. When dumping through unserializing, to want to show each data item in new line @syed mohamed. And yes I also want to store each item to a variable.

Comment: I tried using <pre> and still it doesn't work @b0s3

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>'.var_dump(unserialize($data)).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Any specific need for using var_dump()? Try this code below

echo $data;

OR

echo unserialize($data);

OR

Run through the $data array using a for loop and echo/print only those parameters which you need to show.